# angular2 use elvis operator inside ngfor

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an ngFor which iterates a list.
Now My requirement is that depdending on a condition , the loop should iterate two different lists.Something like below.

```
<div *ngFor="let student of students">
```

this was the existing code .

```
 <div *ngFor="let student of (showAll=true)?students:studentsDetailList">
```

How to achieve something like this?

Comment: cant you handle this in component class? try `let stdn = (showAll=true)?students:studentsDetailList; let student of stdn`

Comment: i am looking for some solutions with in the template itself

Comment: did you try this `<div *ngFor="let stdn = (showAll=true)?students:studentsDetailList; let student of stdn">`

Comment: I added the answer which is working.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div *ngFor = let student of (showAll?students:studentsDetailList)>
```

this syntax is working fine

Answer (score 1):

Consider putting that in the component class, not in the template.

So create a property:

```
 boundList: students[];
```

And in the code somewhere (ngOnInit maybe?) set it appropriately.

```
  if (this.showAll) {
     this.boundList = this.students;
  } else {
     this.boundList = this.studentsDetailList;
  }
```

Or (in one line)

```
this.boundList = this.showAll ? this.students : this.studentsDetailList;
```

Comment: i am looking for some solutions with in the template itself

Comment: Not sure why? It would seem "best practice" to have code/logic in the component class and keep the template simple with basic binding and directives.

Comment: its a simple logic of true/false and felt its an overkill to write it in more than one line